# How to filter a collection of sets by intersection?

Tags: java, algorithm, set

I need to union a collection of sets by intersection of sets and write a function with such signature

```
Collection<Set<Integer>> filter(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection);
```

Here is a simple example of sets

```
1) {1,2,3}
2) {4}
3) {1,5}
4) {4,7}
5) {3,5}
```

In this example we can see that sets `1`, `3`, and `5` intersect. We can rewrite it as a new set `{1,2,3,5}`. Also we have two sets that have intersections as well. They're `2` and `4`, and we can create a new set `{4,7}`. The output result will be a collection of two sets: `{1,2,3,5}` and `{4,7}`.

I don't know from which point to start solving this task.

Comment: Can you be more Specific what the final output should be ? A power Set ?

Comment: Sure. It should be a collection of two sets (`{1,2,3,5}` and `{4,7}`).

Comment: @ketrox a power of any given set could be random.

Comment: The examples you give don't seem to be intersections. e.g. an intersection of 2 and 4 would be `{4}`, and an intersection of 1, 2 and 5 would be `{}`.

Comment: I mean two or more sets should have common element/s. Is it an intersection? In my example you can see that between sets there are connections. If it would be a set `{5}` then it'd be connected to `{1,2,3}` via `{1,5}`. So elements in the set we should treat as connections.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: This isn't really a "filter" if the output consists of elements that weren't in the input.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yeah, it's something like `groupBy`.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your use-case. It may be implemented in a more efficient way, but  I guess this should give you an idea to start with:

```
private static Collection<Set<Integer>> mergeIntersections(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {
    Collection<Set<Integer>> processedCollection = mergeIntersectionsInternal(collection);
    while (!isMergedSuccessfully(processedCollection)) {
        processedCollection = mergeIntersectionsInternal(processedCollection);
    }
    return processedCollection;
}

private static boolean isMergedSuccessfully(Collection<Set<Integer>> processedCollection) {
    if (processedCollection.size() <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    final Set<Integer> mergedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    int totalNumbers = 0;
    for (Set<Integer> set : processedCollection) {
        totalNumbers += set.size();
        mergedNumbers.addAll(set);
    }
    if (totalNumbers > mergedNumbers.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static Collection<Set<Integer>> mergeIntersectionsInternal(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {
    final Collection<Set<Integer>> processedCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    // ITERATE OVER ALL SETS
    for (final Set<Integer> numberSet : collection) {
        for (final Integer number : numberSet) {
            boolean matched = false;
            // ITERATE OVER ALL PROCESSED SETS COLLECTION
            for (final Set<Integer> processedSet : processedCollection) {
                // CHECK OF THERE IS A MATCH
                if (processedSet.contains(number)) {
                    matched = true;
                    // MATCH FOUND, MERGE THE SETS
                    processedSet.addAll(numberSet);
                    // BREAK OUT OF PROCESSED COLLECTION LOOP
                    break;
                }
            }
            // IF NOT MATCHED THEN ADD AS A COLLECTION ITEM
            if (!matched) {
                processedCollection.add(new HashSet<>(numberSet));
            }
        }
    }
    return processedCollection;
}
```

This is how it executed it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Collection<Set<Integer>> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        set1.add(1);
        set1.add(2);
        set1.add(3);
        collection.add(set1);

        final Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
        set2.add(4);
        collection.add(set2);

        final Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>();
        set3.add(1);
        set3.add(5);
        collection.add(set3);

        final Set<Integer> set4 = new HashSet<>();
        set4.add(4);
        set4.add(7);
        collection.add(set4);

        final Set<Integer> set5 = new HashSet<>();
        set5.add(3);
        set5.add(5);
        collection.add(set5);

        System.out.println(mergeIntersections(collection));

    }
```

Comment: I doubt this works as required.  If set A intersects with B and C, I don't see any mechanism that prevents both AuBuC *and* BuC from ending up in the output list.  Also, this looks like O(something large) runtime.

Comment: Yes, the output will be a collection of three sets (`{1,2,3,5}`, `{5,2}`, `{4}`).

Comment: @Mark. I tested it against the example set values mentioned by you and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh, right, yes - it mutates the input sets.  That's cheating :/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Oliver. I've fixed the mutation.

Comment: @AjayDeshwal if you have a such input `{1,2,3}`, `{2,5}`, `{4}` then you expect to get two sets in result collection `{1,2,3,5}` and `{4}`, but the result collection in your solution will have three sets which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs guys. Fixed the scenario. http://ideone.com/ilAMPD

Comment: Mark, I believe you were expecting the input collection to be mutated because the case you posted was working earlier as well before the fix. @Oliver posted a genuine bug which has been fixed now. Please test the solution against the collection returned by method, the input collection is not mutated.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my go. It deletes all sets from the input collection, this could be easily fixed by making a copy first. It does not modify each set in the input collection. With my implementation Ajay’s main method prints `[[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 7]]`.

```
Collection<Set<Integer>> filter(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {
    Collection<Set<Integer>> mergedSets = new ArrayList<>(collection.size());
    // for each set at a time, merge it with all sets that intersect it
    while (! collection.isEmpty()) {
        // take out the first set; make a copy as not to mutate original sets
        Set<Integer> currentSet = new HashSet<>(removeOneElement(collection));
        // find all intersecting sets and merge them into currentSet
        // the trick is to continue merging until we find no intersecting
        boolean mergedAny;
        do {
            mergedAny = false;
            Iterator<Set<Integer>> it = collection.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Set<Integer> candidate = it.next();
                if (intersect(currentSet, candidate)) {
                    it.remove();
                    currentSet.addAll(candidate);
                    mergedAny = true;
                }
            }
        } while (mergedAny);
        mergedSets.add(currentSet);
    }
    return mergedSets;
}

private static Set<Integer> removeOneElement(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {
    Iterator<Set<Integer>> it = collection.iterator();
    Set<Integer> element = it.next();
    it.remove();
    return element;
}

/** @return true if the sets have at least one element in common */
private static boolean intersect(Set<Integer> leftSet, Set<Integer> rightSet) {
    // don’t mutate, take a copy
    Set<Integer> copy = new HashSet<>(leftSet);
    copy.retainAll(rightSet);
    return ! copy.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: If performance is important and your members are in a not too wide range (say, 1 through 100 or maybe 1 through 1000), you will want to look into java.util.BitSet for developing a more efficient implementation.

Comment: An important comment! I recommend you copy this comment into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to solve this problem is using Undirected Graphs, where you connect an element from an input set with at least one other element from the same set, and then look for the Connected Components.

So the graph representation of your example is:

[image]

And from that we can easily infer the Connected Components: {1, 2, 3, 5} and {4, 7}.

Here is my code:

```
Collection<Set<Integer>> filter(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {

    // Build the Undirected Graph represented as an adjacency list
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjacents = new HashMap<>();
    for (Set<Integer> integerSet : collection) {
        if (!integerSet.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Integer> it = integerSet.iterator();
            int node1 = it.next();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int node2 = it.next();

                if (!adjacents.containsKey(node1)) {
                    adjacents.put(node1, new HashSet<>());
                }
                if (!adjacents.containsKey(node2)) {
                    adjacents.put(node2, new HashSet<>());
                }
                adjacents.get(node1).add(node2);
                adjacents.get(node2).add(node1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Run DFS on each node to collect the Connected Components
    Collection<Set<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    for (int start : adjacents.keySet()) {
        if (!visited.contains(start)) {
            Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<>();
            Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
            stack.push(start);
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                int node1 = stack.pop();
                visited.add(node1);
                resultSet.add(node1);
                for (int node2 : adjacents.get(node1)) {
                    if (!visited.contains(node2)) {
                        stack.push(node2);
                    }
                }
            }
            result.add(resultSet);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why everyone is providing complete verbatim solutions to this particular question.  That's not very Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Because It's funny

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution is [Union-Find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

An implemtation:

```
public class UnionFind {

    Set<Integer> all = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> representants = new HashSet<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> parents = new HashMap<>();

    public void union(int p0, int p1) {
        int cp0 = find(p0);
        int cp1 = find(p1);
        if (cp0 != cp1) {
            int size0 = parents.get(cp0);
            int size1 = parents.get(cp1);
            if (size1 < size0) {
                int swap = cp0;
                cp0 = cp1;
                cp1 = swap;
            }
            parents.put(cp0, size0 + size1);
            parents.put(cp1, cp0);
            representants.remove(cp1);
        }
    }

    public int find(int p) {
        Integer result = parents.get(p);
        if (result == null) {
            all.add(p);
            parents.put(p, -1);
            representants.add(p);
            result = p;
        } else if (result < 0) {
            result = p;
        } else {
            result = find(result);
            parents.put(p, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Collection<Set<Integer>> getGroups() {
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer representant : representants) {
            result.put(representant, new HashSet<>(-parents.get(representant)));
        }
        for (Integer value : all) {
            result.get(find(value)).add(value);
        }
        return result.values();
    }

    public static Collection<Set<Integer>> filter(Collection<Set<Integer>> collection) {
        UnionFind groups = new UnionFind();
        for (Set<Integer> set : collection) {
            if (!set.isEmpty()) {
                Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
                int first =  groups.find(it.next());
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    groups.union(first, it.next());
                }
            }
        }
        return groups.getGroups();
    }
}
```